# What is the difference between in list and select in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 2 queries, I want to know which is the best query

```
Model::select('id')->where('status','1')->first();


Model::lists('id')->where('status','1')->first();
```

Please let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is better because it gets only one object. But a better way to get ID of the first row with `status = 1` is to use the [`value()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results) method:

```
Model::where('status', '1')->value('id');
```

The second query is bad because it loads all IDs into memory and then filters them.